# How to listen to Flash video loading -- firefox-adds-on sdk?

Tags: events, firefox, event-handling, firefox-addon-sdk

I am writing adds-on to catch the url of youtube video, in the following Hierarchy :

```
// require tab.module.
// listen onTab.ready.
// Get the tab.url. 
// If the url domain is youtube.
// Javascript request to get the direct .flv link.
// download the link.
```

But I figured out that other sites can embedd  youtube videos.

I will really grateful to anyone give me hint about getting that embedded videos or the event which can catch them.